# db.sqlite3, ,settings.py for heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, sqlite

```
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
NameError: name 'DATABASES' is not defined
```

I'm getting this error while doing heroku run python manage.py syncdb command.

initially I wrote it like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config()
}
```

but then I was getting this error

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named psycopg2
```

what is the correct syntax for sqlite3 database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you are asking about sqlite databases. The code you have given is for Postres, which is correct, as you simply can't use sqlite on Heroku.

The error you are getting appears to be because you haven't included `psycopg2` in your requirements.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

The second bit of code (the way you originally did it) is correct. It sounds like you're not setting the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable, though. `dj_database_url.config()` requires you to set a `DATABASE_URL` environment variable, or supply a default database URL to `config()`. Its README [explains more](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url#usage).